# Python, декартово дерево поиска

Tags: python, книги, дерево, бинарное-дерево

Добрый день!

Я новичок и пытаюсь сейчас реализировать **декартово дерево поиска на python**.
Нужно написать несколько реализаций: 
- *RandomTreap:* использование рандомных переменных в качестве приоритетов
- *DynamicTreap:* когда при каждом обращении к элементу его приоритет повышается и дерево переструктурируется, таким образом элементы с наибольшей частотой обращения передвигаются наверх. При первом внедрении элемента его приоритет равен 1.

*Идеи:*
У меня уже есть реализация бинарного дерева поиска на питоне, имею представление, как написать функции поворота дерева.
Опираясь на реализацию бинарного дерева, можно ее видоизменить, добавив атрибут priority. И изменить функцию insert: если ключа еще нет в дереве, то он добавляется как, как в бинарном дереве, а потом дерево поворачивается.
Если ключ есть, то в RandomTreap ничего не происходит, а в DynamicTreap приоритет увеличивается на 1 и дерево поворачивается.

*Просьба:*
Мне пока сложно написать все это сразу, поэтому предварительно хотелось бы *почитать хорошие описания/ частичную реализацию на питоне,* чтобы во всем хорошенько разобраться. Увы, похоже, что из-за скорости декартовы деревья поиска обычно не пишут на пионе, и я не могу найти в интренете почти ничего хорошего. Может быть, кто-то может посоветовать хорошие ссылки?

Заранее огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: Поглядите сайты algolist.ru, e-maxx.ru, infomatics.mccme.ru

Answer (score 1):

Ознакомиться с созданием различных куч и деревьев можно по книге Problem Solving with Algorithms and Data Structures, рабочая ссылка на перевод: http://aliev.me/runestone/index.html

Про декартовы деревья хорошая статья, где описана реализация методов:
http://opentrains.mipt.ru/zksh/files/zksh2015/lectures/zksh_cartesian.pdf.

Надеюсь я вам хоть немного помог.

Comment: Деннис, огромное спасибо! :)